# NodeJs-MySQL object property undefined

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I don't know why I can't access my property.

```
connection.query("call VerifyAccountToken(0, null)", function(err, rows, fields) {
    if(err) console.log("Error: " + err);

    console.log("SQLRet: ", rows[0].result);
    console.log(rows);
    console.log(fields);
});
```

VerifyAccountToken returns a single row/column result with the column named 'result'.
The console outputs the following:

> SQLRet:  undefined
>
> [ [ { result: 0 } ],
>     { fieldCount: 0,
>       affectedRows: 0,
>       insertId: 0,
>       serverStatus: 2,
>       warningCount: 1,
>       message: '',
>       protocol41: true,
>       changedRows: 0 } ]
>
> [ [ { catalog: 'def',
>         db: '',
>         table: '',
>         orgTable: '',
>         name: 'result',
>         orgName: 'iRes',
>         filler1: ,
>         charsetNr: 63,
>         length: 11,
>         type: 3,
>         flags: 0,
>         decimals: 0,
>         filler2: ,
>         default: undefined,
>         zeroFill: false,
>         protocol41: true } ],
>     undefined ]

Everything I know tells me this should work.

Comment: Apparently I needed to use rows[0][0].result... that seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok apparently I needed to  use

```
rows[0][0].result;
```

I'm not sure why node-mysql nests stored procedures' returned results.

Comment: Presumably that would be because a MySQL stored procedure can return multiple result sets, which is a very useful capability, and rows[0] could be the first one of "n"; see the last paragraph here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines-syntax.html